# Cannot run swig tutorial

Tags: c++, python-3.x, swig

I am working with

-Windows 10 64 bit

-Swig 3.0.12, which I downloaded from http://www.swig.org/download.html

-Python 3.5.4  [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

-MinGW7.3.0 64 bit

It is the first time that I use swig to extend my python application with c++ code. I tried to compile the example code of swig official website [a link](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html). Python 3.5 had already the libpython.a inside the libs folder, which is needed to compile with mingw, so I used it. I followed the tutorial from [a link](https://suryagaddipati.wordpress.com/2008/03/12/creating-python-extensions-in-cc-with-swig-on-windows/)! to compile swig in windows.

Specifically, I run the following

swig –python –c example.i

gcc -c *.c

gcc -c example_wrap.cxx -Ic:\python35\include

gcc -shared *.o -o _example.pyd -Lc:\python35\libs -lpython35

Up to here, all ok!

But when I try to import it in Python35 ,I get the following error message

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.379]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

> python
>
> import example
>
> example.fact(3)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   TypeError: in method 'fact', argument 1 of type 'int'

Where is the error ?

```
/* File : example.c */

double  My_variable  = 3.0;

/* Compute factorial of n */
int fact(int n) {
  if (n <= 1)
    return 1;
  else
    return n*fact(n-1);
}

/* Compute n mod m */
int my_mod(int n, int m) {
  return(n % m);
}
```

```
/* File : example.i */
%module example
%{
/* Put headers and other declarations here */
extern double My_variable;
extern int    fact(int);
extern int    my_mod(int n, int m);
%}

extern double My_variable;
extern int    fact(int);
extern int    my_mod(int n, int m);
```

```
# This file was automatically generated by SWIG (http://www.swig.org).
# Version 3.0.12
#
# Do not make changes to this file unless you know what you are doing--modify
# the SWIG interface file instead.

from sys import version_info as _swig_python_version_info
if _swig_python_version_info >= (2, 7, 0):
    def swig_import_helper():
        import importlib
        pkg = __name__.rpartition('.')[0]
        mname = '.'.join((pkg, '_example')).lstrip('.')
        try:
            return importlib.import_module(mname)
        except ImportError:
            return importlib.import_module('_example')
    _example = swig_import_helper()
    del swig_import_helper
elif _swig_python_version_info >= (2, 6, 0):
    def swig_import_helper():
        from os.path import dirname
        import imp
        fp = None
        try:
            fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_example', [dirname(__file__)])
        except ImportError:
            import _example
            return _example
        try:
            _mod = imp.load_module('_example', fp, pathname, description)
        finally:
            if fp is not None:
                fp.close()
        return _mod
    _example = swig_import_helper()
    del swig_import_helper
else:
    import _example
del _swig_python_version_info

try:
    _swig_property = property
except NameError:
    pass  # Python < 2.2 doesn't have 'property'.

try:
    import builtins as __builtin__
except ImportError:
    import __builtin__

def _swig_setattr_nondynamic(self, class_type, name, value, static=1):
    if (name == "thisown"):
        return self.this.own(value)
    if (name == "this"):
        if type(value).__name__ == 'SwigPyObject':
            self.__dict__[name] = value
            return
    method = class_type.__swig_setmethods__.get(name, None)
    if method:
        return method(self, value)
    if (not static):
        if _newclass:
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
        else:
            self.__dict__[name] = value
    else:
        raise AttributeError("You cannot add attributes to %s" % self)


def _swig_setattr(self, class_type, name, value):
    return _swig_setattr_nondynamic(self, class_type, name, value, 0)


def _swig_getattr(self, class_type, name):
    if (name == "thisown"):
        return self.this.own()
    method = class_type.__swig_getmethods__.get(name, None)
    if method:
        return method(self)
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (class_type.__name__, name))


def _swig_repr(self):
    try:
        strthis = "proxy of " + self.this.__repr__()
    except __builtin__.Exception:
        strthis = ""
    return "<%s.%s; %s >" % (self.__class__.__module__, self.__class__.__name__, strthis,)

try:
    _object = object
    _newclass = 1
except __builtin__.Exception:
    class _object:
        pass
    _newclass = 0


def fact(arg1):
    return _example.fact(arg1)
fact = _example.fact

def my_mod(n, m):
    return _example.my_mod(n, m)
my_mod = _example.my_mod
# This file is compatible with both classic and new-style classes.

cvar = _example.cvar
```

Comment: example.i and example.c are correct.  The gcc looks correct but I think it is missing a `-fpic` option.  I don't have MingGW installed, but the code works with a Microsoft compiler w/ added __declspec(dllexport) as needed by that compiler.  BTW, there is no swig `-c` switch, so I assume that is a typo.

Comment: First of all, thank you. Secondly, could you please write down for me the commands that you wrote to produce the wrapper in msvs. Which python and msvs version you use ?

Comment: I added an answer.  To clarify my previous comment, `__declspec(export)` is only needed if you build a C DLL, and then a Python extension wrapping it.  In my answer below I linked the wrapper and the C code together so it isn't needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-fpic` might be missing from `gcc`, but here's a VS2017 64-bit solution as a working example using Python 3.6 (64-bit version of compiler and Python).

Using your exact `example.i` and `example.c`:

```
C:\example>swig -python example.i

C:\example>cl /MD /LD /W3 /Ic:\python36\include /Fe_example.pyd example_wrap.c example.c /link /libpath:c:\python36\libs
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27027.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

example_wrap.c
example.c
Generating Code...
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27027.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/dll
/implib:_example.lib
/out:_example.pyd
/libpath:c:\python36\libs
example_wrap.obj
example.obj
   Creating library _example.lib and object _example.exp

C:\example>py
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import example
>>> example.cvar.My_variable
3.0
>>> example.fact(3)
6
>>> example.my_mod(7,2)
1
```

You can also use `distutils` and create a `setup.py` ([ref](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn6))

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

example_module = Extension('_example',
                           sources=['example.i', 'example.c'],
                           )

setup (name = 'example',
       version = '0.1',
       author      = "SWIG Docs",
       description = """Simple swig example from docs""",
       ext_modules = [example_module],
       py_modules = ["example"],
       )
```

Command:

```
py setup.py build_ext --inplace
```